# Sorting the array ,it contains Date,month

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I want to sort array according to Dates and Months value.I am using this code

```
 NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
    revereseorder=[dateAarray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
    NSLog(@"date order %@",revereseorder);
```

I have got the response like below:

```
 date order (
    "01-11-2014",
    "01-12-2014",
    "02-11-2014",
    "02-12-2014",
    "03-11-2014",
    "03-12-2014",
    "04-11-2014",
    "04-12-2014",
    "05-11-2014",
    "05-12-2014",
    "06-11-2014",
    "06-12-2014",
    "07-11-2014",
    "07-12-2014",
    "08-11-2014",
    "08-12-2014",
    "09-11-2014",
    "09-12-2014",
    "10-11-2014",
    "10-12-2014",
    "11-11-2014",
    "11-12-2014",
    "12-11-2014",
    "12-12-2014",
    "13-11-2014",
    "13-12-2014",
    "14-11-2014",
    "15-11-2014",
    "16-11-2014",
    "17-11-2014",
    "18-11-2014",
    "19-11-2014",
    "20-11-2014"

)
```

but i need to display the response current date to descending order based on the current month.Can you please suggest me how can its solve? thank you@

Comment: You will need to convert the date to `NSDate` objects, Since they are not string that are sorted as strings.

Comment: You're going to have trouble with 2015.  You do not need to convert dates to NSDate, but you should use a yyyy-MM-dd format.  "i need to display the response current date to descending order based on the current month" is a bit hard to parse -- could you explain that better?

Comment: ya ofcourse @HotLicks,ok i will use YYYY-MM-DD format,thank you.

Comment: @iOS2340 or you could use the code in my answer. That means you don't have to change anything and it will work for any year, month, day etc... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert the strings into actual NSDate objects if you want to sort them properly.

You can use the comparator function to sort them like this...

```
NSArray *dateStringArray = //your array...

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";

NSArray *sortedArray = [dateStringArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *string1, NSString *string2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string2];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

If you want descending order then just change the last line of the comparator to...

```
return [date2 compare:date1];
```

Comment: your code is fine @Fogmeister, but unused sortedArray one warning is  there i.e Un used variable sorted array.

Comment: Well yeah, if you're not using the sorted array then you will get that warning. You could change it to `dateStringArray = blah...`. Because I'm assuming you're using an `NSArray` instead of `NSMutableArray` then you cannot sort the array directly. You have to create a new array from the sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *fmtdt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtdt setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSComparator compareTimes = ^(id string1, id string2)
{
    NSDate *time1 = [fmtdt dateFromString:string1];
    NSDate *time2 = [fmtdt dateFromString:string2];
    return [time1 compare:time2];
};
NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES comparator:compareTimes];
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSDateFormatter is the easy way, but if you do not want to use NSDateFormatter, then you have to tokenize each date by '-' and sort, this requires more processing though.

NSArray *token = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"-"];